# Did not find expected hey

Tags: yaml, hugo

In my developing Hugo web site a content file is generating a server error that it did not do before. The front matter in the education.md file is:

```yaml
---
identifier: "schools"
title: "Education"
date: "2022-10-18"
description: "My academic traning."
menu:
  main:
    parent: "about"
      weight: 3
---
```

I ran this front matter through an online YAML lint and it reported an error on line 8 (parent), position 5 (p}. The hugo server reports it on line 7 (main:). This is the same format as in the past and the same as other .md files in the parent directory. I'm not seeing why there's an error so I cannot fix it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem here:

```
menu:
  main:
    parent: "about"
      weight: 3
```

`parent` cannot both have a scalar value and be a dictionary. That is, you can do this:

```
main:
  parent: "about"
```

Or you can do this:

```
main:
  parent:
    weight: 3
```

But what you have is not valid YAML. You probably want:

```
menu:
  main:
    parent: "about"
    weight: 3
```

...but I haven't checked the hugo docs to verify that.

Comment: Ah! Mea culpa! I inset the weight line when I shouldn't have. Thank you larsks. Much appreciated.